# Unable to open an image through PIL in googlecolab

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

```
  !wget https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/cnn_class/lena.png
  from PIL import Image 
  im =Image.open('lena.png')
```

UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 im =Image.open('lena.png')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
2929         warnings.warn(message)
2930     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 2931         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
2932     )
2933

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'lena.png'

Comment: I presume the `!` allows you to run shell commands, if so, check if Lena is there before you open the file with `!ls -l lena.png`

Answer (score 1):

The link you are using to `wget` is all wrong. You are actually sending a GET request to the html file instead of the image.
Here's the actual image link for you :)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/master/cnn_class/lena.png

Comment: ya u r right but why it would not be open from link that i use....@abjklk